# How I get  URL from webview on click

Tags: android

How can I get "clicked URL" from `webview` on its click event??

`@Override`
    `public void onClick(View v) {`

```
    if( v.getId() == R.id.webview) {

        //Here i want to get clicked url
    }


}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I got the answer, here it is

 `webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
             webView.loadUrl(url);
                 // Here the String url hold 'Clicked URL'
             return false;
            }
        });`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() { 
            public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url){
                webView.loadUrl(url); 
                // Here the String url hold 'Clicked URL' 
                return false; 
            } 
        });
```

Comment: This answer is misleading. Nothing in the documentation of the `shouldOverrideUrlLoading` method (http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebViewClient.html) says anything about the callback being triggered on user-clicked url's only. This callback is called even for url's being loaded by a script on the page for example, which in turn means that you can not know in the callback method whether the url was triggered by a user click or a script.