# Button for copying url- webview

Tags: java, android, button, webview

i'm working on a webview project, in which i don't have a url bar, so i want a button in the webview's layout that would copy the current page URL on the clipboard so that i can paste it somewhere else.

Thanks

below is my code -

```
package com.Exmple.avd;
```

package com.ApkEngine.avd;

```
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.ClipData;
import android.content.ClipboardManager;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.KeyEvent;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
import android.webkit.WebView;
import android.webkit.WebViewClient;
import android.widget.Button;

public class Search extends Activity {

private WebView mWebView;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_search);
    Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

        String url = mWebView.getUrl();
        ClipboardManager clipboard = (ClipboardManager)     getSystemService(CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
        ClipData clip = ClipData.newPlainText("label", url);
        clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);

        }

    });
    mWebView = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wvsearch);
    mWebView.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    mWebView.setWebViewClient(new HelloWebViewClient());
    mWebView.getSettings().setBuiltInZoomControls(true);
    mWebView.loadUrl("http://www.google.com"); 
}
 private class HelloWebViewClient extends WebViewClient {
@Override
public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView webview, String url)
{


webview.loadUrl(url);
return true;
}
}

 @Override
 public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event)
 {

 if ((keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_BACK) && mWebView.canGoBack())

{
mWebView.goBack();
return true;
}
return super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event);


 }
}
```

Comment: That's nice. Any problems?

Comment: If you don't know how to get the current url try to search for `android webview get current url`.  don't know how to listen for a button click search for `android button click event` - Good luck

Comment: thanks, i will search for it

Comment: i find an example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6623594/how-i-get-url-from-webview-on-click

Comment: but dont know how to do the same on button click...

Answer (score 2):

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button1);

    button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

           String url = mWebView.getUrl();
           if(android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.HONEYCOMB) {
               android.text.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.text.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE);
               clipboard.setText(url);
           } else {
               android.content.ClipboardManager clipboard = (android.content.ClipboardManager) getSystemService(Context.CLIPBOARD_SERVICE); 
               android.content.ClipData clip = android.content.ClipData.newPlainText("text label", url);
               clipboard.setPrimaryClip(clip);
          }
        }

    });
```

The onclick import: paste it to the top of your java file then restart

```
import android.view.View.OnClickListener;
```

Comment: this is not working, all it copies is "text to clip"

Comment: Code edited, try it now. Also I would advise you to read up some tutorials

Answer (score 0):

```
public void copy_paste(View view) { 
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, Search.class);
    String webUrl = mWebView.getUrl();
}
```